# model shows null on postback in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm beginner in C#. When I postback the form to server its show null value in model. Pls help I have no clue what to do?

**Controller Code**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
public ActionResult ChangeUserDetail(ChangeUserDataModel model)
{
    // ....
}
```

**Model Code**:

```
public class ChangeUserDataModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Update Field")]
    public string Change { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**View Code**:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
{
    var model2 = new Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel();
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => model2.UserName)
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => model2.UserName, new 
                SelectList(ViewBag.UserNames, "Value", "Text")
        </div>
    </div>
    .....
}
```

Comment: Remove `var model2 = new Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel();` and use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName, new SelectList(ViewBag.UserNames, "Value", "Text")` - look at the html your generating - the `name` attributes have no relationship to your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in view, should work.

```
    @model Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel

using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
     {

       <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.UserName)
         <div class="col-md-8">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.UserName, new 
         SelectList(ViewBag.UserNames, "Value", "Text")
         </div>
       </div>
}
```

Comment: i have several models in same page @model Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel gives another error

Comment: i use partial view method to use multiple model in  same page

Comment: create a class with all the models in as properties and then push through controller as model.

Comment: I resolve my problem using partial result view method

Answer (score 2):

I think that this line

```
var model2 = new Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel();
```

is not corrrect. Why would you need to initiate here a model?

In an MVC architecture the View receives the Model that is passed from the Controller. The View doesn't create the Model that will use later. So normally in your GET request you should pass an epmty model and on POST this model would be created based on the values that the form you POST contains.

In terms of code. The expected is something like this:

**View**

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserDetail", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
{      
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserName, new 
                SelectList(ViewBag.UserNames, "Value", "Text")
        </div>
   </div>
}
```

Furthermore, at the top of your view you should define the type of the Model you expcet:

```
@model Webrims.Models.AdminViewModel.ChangeUserDataModel
```

Comment: because i have several models in same page